# notify-send to other user on the same system

Tags: ubuntu, debian, notifications

Is it possible to use notify-send to send messages to other users on the system?
preferably to a specified user, but system wide would work aswell.

Ubuntu/Debian with libnotify installed

Comment: See [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/344377/7286) for an example that works with Ubuntu 16.04, even from a script started by root in crontab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the other users password you can do `sudo -u somedude notify-send Hello`. somedude must have an X-session started.

Edit:
Found this script for use with cron:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
export DISPLAY=:0.0
export $(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -session)/environ )
TIME=$1
shift
/usr/bin/notify-send -t 36000 $1 $2
```

Comment: with slight modification, that script does what i need it to do, thanks

Comment: didn't you miss one hyphen before `-session`?

Comment: no @vladkras `pgrep` is supposed to be getting the pid of the X-session manager, i.e. lxde-session, gnome-session etc. 
That script is a crude hack at best and depends a lot on your system setup. It worked when I answered but doesn't work without modification now, 5 years later.

Comment: It doesn`t work for me either

Answer (score 1):

If the users are on terminals the following commands will be of use -

```
write user [tty]
```

or to send to all users

```
wall
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the following project that implements a user notify: [tinynotify-send](https://github.com/mortbauer/tinynotify-send)

Answer (score 1):

I needed similar tool to send notification to all sessions. Here is my solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230062/93227

It scans /proc to find all session busses and then it executes notify-send on each of it (once per bus). All arguments are passed unchanged to real notify-send.

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/grep -sozZe '^DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=[a-zA-Z0-9:=,/-]*$' /proc/*/environ \
| /usr/bin/php -r '
        $busses = array();
        array_shift($argv);
        while($ln = fgets(STDIN)) {
                list($f, $env) = explode("\0", $ln, 2);
                if (file_exists($f)) {
                        $user = fileowner($f);
                        $busses[$user][trim($env)] = true;
                }
        }
        foreach ($busses as $user => $user_busses) {
                foreach ($user_busses as $env => $true) {
                        if (pcntl_fork()) {
                                posix_seteuid($user);
                                $env_array = array("DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" => preg_replace("/^DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/", "", $env));
                                pcntl_exec("/usr/bin/notify-send", $argv, $env_array);
                        }
                }
        }
' -- "$@"
```